# Cant open EAGLE Schematic file in Altium10

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

Iam using Altium designer version 10 and I cant open a EAGLE schematic file  in this.

EAGLE importer is not in the import wizard.
can any one help me?
[image: import wizard]

[image: get more importers]

Comment: Have you tried the "Get More Importers..." link? (Some importers only work in later versions).

Answer (score 2):

The EAGLE importer wasn't introduced until AD14, so unfortunately you probably won't be able to get it for AD10.

https://www.altium.com/video-eagle-importer/

If you have an active Altium subscription, you should be able to upgrade at no extra cost.